# How can one query Solr for gmail address ignoring dots and pluses?

Tags: regex, solr, gmail

I'd like to query a Solr database for text containing a given gmail address.  I'd like to search by the canonical gmail address, and get any results that gmail interprets as the same address.

**Example**

Searching for `somebody@gmail.com` should match all of the following strings:

- `somebody@gmail.com`
- `some.body@gmail.com`
- `somebody+somewhere@gmail.com`

But not match:

- `somebody.else@gmail.com`
- `some+body@gmail.com`

Is this possible with a regex or some other way?

---

Note: Info about gmail's "dot's don't matter" and plus sign extensions can be found at https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

Comment: Is the field only being used for gmail addresses, or for any email address and the processing should only happen for gmail addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know some type of search will be a requirement, you deal with it at the indexing time for efficiency purposes.

So, you want to extract those email addresses and put them into a separate field for pre-processing (removing dot and removing +anything). Then you search both fields, possibly boosting on the email one.

You may find it easier using [UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory and TypeTokenFilterFactory (as a whitelist by email type)](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/processors/conf/schema.xml#L46) to keep just email addresses in the copied field.

Answer (score 0):

- With a regex: most probably is possible, I don't use regex that much but I think it is.
- But anyway, I advise you do some work at index time to make this easier. You just index two fields, one with original content (just in case), and another copyField with the . and +somwhere stuff removed. Then you have more tools available to you